# Surface crossing itself plotted from x,y,z data

Tags: plotting, visualization, matlab

In Matlab I am generating this surface for example.

[image]

It is plotted in for loop, so in each iteration I plot one ellipse or whatever itself crossing curve. Number of iteration is high so it produce this nice effect of surface. It is quite important to note that for each point there can be several corresponding points as can be seen from the picture above.
However I would prefer to plot it like solid surface with lighting effect and opacity control to appear more like manifold in this picture
[image]

Is it even possible to do this in Wolfram Mathematica? I am not good at all in Wolfram, I work mostly in Matlab but honestly, what Mathematica does really well is nice surface/shape plotting.

I can prepare x,y,z coordinate for each iteration and save it into XLS or CSV. The tricky condition is that it is actually produced step by step in for loop so data are like this also. Can you provide canonical example how to proceed then in case it can be done in Mathematica?

**Edit.** So far I have dat file organized as folows (sample only)

```
       -6.7180071e-01  -7.3984869e-03   1.0734382e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   1.8511572e-03   1.1679920e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   1.1089280e-02   1.2554582e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   2.0259866e-02   1.3353084e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   2.9307326e-02   1.4070609e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   3.8492163e-02   1.4723953e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   4.7426245e-02   1.5281519e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   5.6051512e-02   1.5739706e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   6.4311924e-02   1.6095560e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   7.2255363e-02   1.6349422e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   7.9716047e-02   1.6494168e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   8.6644245e-02   1.6528842e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   9.2993775e-02   1.6453217e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   9.8871061e-02   1.6261139e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   1.0405126e-01   1.5954476e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   1.0849790e-01   1.5535376e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   1.1217966e-01   1.5006770e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   1.1499108e-01   1.4394115e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   1.1704252e-01   1.3686300e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   1.1832039e-01   1.2887976e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   1.1881620e-01   1.2004395e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   1.1856663e-01   1.1102102e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   1.1762564e-01   1.0134983e-01
  -6.7180071e-01   1.1599865e-01   9.1086631e-02
  -6.7180071e-01   1.1369505e-01   8.0291191e-02
  -6.7180071e-01   1.1087951e-01   6.9555711e-02
  -6.7180071e-01   1.0747540e-01   5.8450219e-02
  -6.7180071e-01   1.0350073e-01   4.7033696e-02
  -6.7180071e-01   9.8976548e-02   3.5366808e-02
```

each column correspond to x,y,z coordinate respectively. In mathematica I am calling this

```
Data = Import["F:\\matlab2wolfram.dat", "Table"][[All, {1, 2, 3}]]
ListSurfacePlot3D [Data]
```

Produced plot is hardly the expected result
[image]

Comment: `ListSurfacePlot3D`?

Comment: Will give it a try, thank you

Comment: see my edit please

Comment: You should use square brackets `[,]`: `ListSurfacePlot3D[Data]`

Comment: Ok, brackets helped :) but as you can see, ListSurfacePlot3D is not producing what I would expect.

Comment: Since you have imported the data you must have it in list form. Post your data (or sample of data)  as a list so that it can be copy and pasted into a notebook.

Comment: It might be easier to re-generate the data in mathematica with `Table` or the like (if you do this, it's generally good to avoid `For` in Mathematica, as the language is such that there are lots of more efficient and simpler ways to build up lists with `Table`, `Array`, `NestList`, `FoldList`, and `Sow`/`Reap` if necessary.) I say this because it seems like there's structure in how you expect to connect these points that's missing from the list of data points themselves.